# 2 cell Li-ion battery charger malfunctioning

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I am attempting to use a prototype 2 cell Li-ion battery charger, but the charger appears to be overheating.  The charger uses a monolithic power MP2672GD IC as its basis [battery charger IC](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP2672/).  Circuit was taken from datasheet.

When I activate it the STAT and ACOK lights are solid and the battery appears to be charging.  But after about 1min the 5V LDO supplying the battery management IC heats up quite a bit and so does the battery management IC.  Then the STAT and ACOK light start blinking in together.

This seems like excessive current draw, but the main power supply at 14V is reading pretty steady at about 1.1A and without this portion of the circuit, it normally draws about 0.15A.  The LDO IC101 has a huge ground pad and the ground plane is around it although the spokes are pretty thin, but why is it overheating so fast?  Also this board is overkill and has 4 layers all of which have ground planes where no traces are.  The layer directly underneath the top layer is an unbroken ground plane.

The circuit is below, the only thing I have changed is removed the P MOSFETs Q103 and Q104.  With these it seemed like the IC was having difficulty detecting the battery. The battery is located at the top left of the PCB (the 3 prong connection) and the very right of the schematic drawing.

Does anyone know how my charger could be pulling only about 1A from 14V supply and still overheating?

[image: circuit]

[image: footprint1]
[image: footprint with ground plane]

Comment: I'm having trouble detecting the battery too. Where is it connected?

Comment: Anyway, that aside, I'm struggling to understand why you're using an expensive ultra-low dropout regulator to lower 14V to 5V to then step it up again using a boost charger. At 1A the LDO will dissipate 9W of power and get hot very quickly without sufficient heatsinking.

Comment: The charger battery is connected in the top left of the PCB and the very right of the schematic (J1).  Since there are 9W to disipate will I likely need a fan? Or should I add more vias and improve the connection to the ground plane?

Comment: Also the battery management IC heats up quite a bit, I have already limited the charging current to 0.5A but is there another way to lower the thermal stress on the battery management IC?

Comment: 1.1 A x (14-5) V = 9.9 W of dissipation. No wonder it gets hot. Why are you stepping down to 5 V?

Comment: What is the purpose of Q103 and Q104? What are the measured voltages on each cell of the battery?

Comment: @winny the battery IC's input operational voltage is 4.0V to 5.75V so I am stepping down to 5V.

Comment: @BruceAbbott the purpose of Q103,4 was to disconnect the battery from the charger if some logic deemed the battery should not be charged.  This logic was active when the board is on battery power and had no other power source.

Comment: Please calculate the losses and compare it to a buck charger IC which can work directly with your 14 V input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the charge current set to 0.5 A. Therefore at 8.4 V out the boost charger IC must draw at least (8.4/5)*0.5/0.95 = 0.88 A at 5 V.

The LDO dropping from 14 V to 5 V will have to dissipate (14-5)*0.88 = 7.92 W. That's a lot of heat to get rid of. You should replace the linear regulator with a switching type.

With the FETs strapped out the battery will become unbalanced via R114 and R115. Do not leave it this way! When the FETs are turned on ('MotorON' signal inactive?) the battery will become unbalanced via R115. Even when turned 'off' the FETS don't completely disconnect the battery because their body diodes can conduct. It might be better to pull the VLIN pin low to disable charging (when motor is on?) instead.

For correct battery detection and accurate cell voltage measurement the battery should be connected directly to the charger IC (with MID going through R117 to limit balancing current).

Comment: The battery charges when the motor is on (motorON line is high).  Do you mean pull Vlim low instead of Vlin?  If so this is actually already occuring because EN is low when motor on is low.  I just was trying to protect the battery management IC from voltages on its pins when it had no voltage supply.  Thanks for reminding me of R114 and R115 I will remove these now that the MOSFETs are gone.

Comment: Also I think I will replace the LDO with MAX20077ATCA/VY+

Comment: Why would you want to run two switching regulators in series? Better than LDO + switcher, but why not a different li-ion battery charger IC in the first place?

Comment: I see your point but I cannot find many ICs that are designed for 2 cell batteries, have cell balancing, and can tolerate 15V input.

Comment: ...and running the charger from 5V means you can use a standard USB power supply etc. if desired. The charger IC should be fine connected to the battery with no power input, since this can easily happen in typical applications. Internally it has back-to-back MOSFETs that isolate the input from the output when turned off. I can't find a spec for leakage, hopefully its low enough that the battery won't drain significantly when there is no power.

Comment: I will eliminate these P mosfets between the 2-cell battery and the charger IC.  But as far as the power source I am stuck with 14V and there isn't a hope for a USB power supply unless I put one on the board.  I looked around quite a bit for a charger IC that can do what this one can and take 14V input but cheap.  This is all I got so far and adding this switching regulator isn't so bad.